# Consecutive input at Samsung Tizen

Tags: javascript, html, tizen

I’m trying to build a Samsung Smart TV (Tizen) app. Now the app works on real Testing TV Series 6000.

I have four textfields with `autofocus` in the first textfield. The TV keyboard opened and I see the “Done” button. What can I do to have consecutive input with “Next” Button?

Please look at 5.4: https://www.samsungdforum.com/UxGuide/2014/05_text_input.html

I doesn’t find any information about that…

My source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1920, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/keyTizen.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="first">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Dein Name" name="yourName" id="yourName" autofocus />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Band / Interpret deines Wunschsongs" name="band" id="band" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Titel deines Wunschesongs" name="title" id="title" />
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <textarea placeholder="Deine persönliche Grußnachricht" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please le t me know how keyboard is working. Not working for me. Any JS required to open it up or any event required to get it activated?

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'blur' and 'focus' of consecutive text fields using their element id and bind the action to other keys available on keyboard.

Use triggering 'keydown' event to focus to next input.

Specific keyCode for other keys and event listener are described here.

https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen271/index.html